# Chef configure a Node with runlists that can run in events other than while bootstrap?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a requirement to assign a run-list to a node using chef framework. But I see only a capability to run the recipes in the cookbooks during bootstrap of the node. Is there any way to specify "when" to run a recipe in the client instead of running it at bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, it's usual to run `chef-client` either as a service or through `cron`. See esp. the `init_style` attribute of the `chef-client` cookbook: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/chef-client#attributes

Comment: I am developing a PaaS product. So, when one asks for a typical App Server and a DB Server for their aplication, I need to launch instances with that configuration.My Instance is my chef client.Iam using Hosted Chef Server.In future, I may want to update the configuration of the servers in the instance. Or dynamically add new servers to the already existing instance. This will not be possible with the bootstrap command because It will install the chef-client again and run the recipes in the run-list all over again. How to run a recipe in a chef-client while it's already up and running? Thanks